# Oracle 11G Clob column with where clause

Tags: oracle

I am using a query to get data from a `CLOB` column. I need to add a `WHERE` clause to it to only get the rows where `Error = 0` from the CLOB column.

**The query I am using atm is:**

```
select lt.T_ID, lt.SUCCESSFUL_TIMESTAMP,
       clob_xml_element_text(lm.XML_DATA, 'year-of-manufacture') "year",
       clob_xml_element_text(lm.XML_DATA, 'make') "make",
       clob_xml_element_text(lm.XML_DATA, 'model') "model",
       clob_xml_element_text(lm2.XML_DATA, 'mt') "odometer"
from tabletest2 lt
join tabletest lm on lt.T_ID = lm.T_ID
LEFT JOIN tabletest lm2 on lm.T_ID = lm2.T_ID and lm2.TYPE_ID = -129
where lm.TYPE_ID = -29
order by lt.SUCCESSFUL_TIMESTAMP ASC;
```

**Output:**

```
T_ID    SUCCESSFUL_TIMESTAMP    year    make    model odometer
167951  01/01/18 00:00:08.541000000     2009    Kia Sportage 2.0 Auto   82396
167979  01/01/18 00:02:42.613000000     2009    Mazda   2 Sport 5 DR 1.5 4AT    98589
174570  01/01/18 00:03:33.738000000     2015    Mercedes-Benz   CLA-Class CLA 250 2.0P/7AT/SL   null
198700  01/01/18 00:03:35.599000000     2008    Mitsubishi  Galant  null
```

**Expected output**

Remove the two rows where the odometer is null.

**I tried to use:**

`(existsNode(lm2.XML_DATA,'/mt[Error]') = 0)`

It works but when running the query with no limit I get the error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

**UPDATE:**

Updating this question with the tables DDL.

```
CREATE TABLE tabletest
   (
  "TYPE_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "T_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "XML_DATA" CLOB,
  CONSTRAINT tabletest_pk PRIMARY KEY (T_ID)
   );

   CREATE TABLE tabletest2
    (
   "T_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
   "SUCCESSFUL_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL ENABLE,
   CONSTRAINT tabletest2_t_id
    FOREIGN KEY (T_ID)
    REFERENCES tabletest(T_ID)
    );

    INSERT INTO tabletest ("TYPE_ID", "T_ID", "XML_DATA") VALUES 
    (
      '-29',
      1,
      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <l-ana version="2.9">
       <vehicle>
          <Error>0</Error>
          <year-of-manufacture>1999</year-of-manufacture>
          <make>Toyota</make>
          <model>Hilux</model>
          <mt>235998</mt>
       </vehicle>
    </l-ana>'
    );

    INSERT INTO tabletest ("TYPE_ID", "T_ID", "XML_DATA") VALUES 
    (
      '-29',
      2,
      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <l-ana version="2.9">
       <vehicle>
          <Error>10</Error>
          <year-of-manufacture>1989</year-of-manufacture>
          <make>Toyota</make>
          <model>Hilux</model>
          <mt>535998</mt>
       </vehicle>
    </l-ana>'
    );
```

The disare output is to only get records where `Error = 0`.

Comment: `existsNode` is deprecated.  Don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

## Prologue

You are not having problems with a "CLOB column with a WHERE clause".
You are having problems processing XML Documents stored in a `CLOB` field.

This is your third question regarding this task.

I recommend you Read The Fine Manual before you advance on your problem:  [Oracle XML Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/toc.htm)

## existsNode

`existsNode` is deprecated.  Don't use it.

Instead, use:

```
WHERE XMLExists( '/mt[Error="0"]' passing xml_data)
```

## PL/SQL Error

I suspect this might be due to a conversion error.

You should start investigating this error by fixing your Schema such that you are storing numbers as `NUMBER`, dates as `DATE`, and XML Documents as `XMLType`.  Even if this isn't the case, your Schema would be better for it.

My other thought is: your XML Document has a string but you are attempting to extract a number.

Comment: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 31 Column: 62`

Comment: `CLOB` <> `XMLType`.  You need to explicitly convert the `CLOB` to `XMLType` before you use XML functions.  If the conversion fails, then you probably don't have text  (in a `CLOB`) that conforms to XML Specifications. If that is the case, you need to fix your schema to prevent bad data from getting in.

Comment: I see. `and XMLExists('/mt[Error="0"]' passing XMLTYPE(lm2.xml_data))` returns the same error as my original post. `ORA-06502, ORA-06512`. Am I converting correctly to XMLType?

Comment: "Converting correctly?" is the wrong question.  "Is the data actually XML data?" Is the correct question.  If you had stored the data as `XMLType` in the first place, you wouldn't have to research that question.

Comment: sorry, this is getting confusing. I've updated the question with the table DDL. So you have the query I am using, you have the Table DDL and the data. Please, provide me with an answer with the query I am using so I can mark this question as resolved.

Comment: The XMLQuery `/mt[Error=0]` will always return FLASE for the `<l-ana>` XML Documents you  posted in your update.  Just modify the XMLQuery to fit you needs.